# Database Transaction using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I want to implement database transaction using entity framework in two different databases. If any exception occur during the transaction in the second database the changes should roll back from all the databases. If there is no any exception occur in the second database the changes should save in the Databases. For this I wrote the below code. Even all the provided input is correct then it should save the changes successfully but I get exception in this `b3.SaveChanges();` line. The Exception message is

> "The underlying provider failed on Open"

How to implement this one?

```
public static void InsertIntoDb()
    {

        using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {
                using (DB1Entities db1 = new DB1Entities())
                {
                    Employee emp = new Employee();
                    emp.DeptId = 102;
                    emp.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime("10/10/1989");
                    emp.gender = "Male";
                    emp.EmpID = 211;
                    emp.name = "XYZ";
                    db1.Employees.Add(emp);
                    db1.SaveChanges();
                    using (DB3Entities db3 = new DB3Entities())
                    {
                        Department dept = new Department();
                        dept.DeptName = "ABC";
                        dept.DeptId = 680;
                        db3.Departments.Add(dept);
                        db3.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                trans.Complete();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                trans.Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check your connectionstring - it sounds like it might be the problem. Your transaction-code look ok.

Comment: If I comments the first database operation, and then execute only the second one. It is able to save the data in DB3. So i think connection string don't have any issue.

Comment: @Jens Kloster please help to get the answer. Thanks